# float right element in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how can switch red background with green

[image]

my code is:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>

            <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
              <Text>1</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{backgroundColor:'blue', flex: 1}}>
              <Text>2</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{backgroundColor:'green', flex: 1}}>
              <Text>3</Text>
            </View>

          </View>

        </View>
```

How to fix the problem by changing the style?
please help

Comment: Try `row-reverse` for `flexDirection`.

Comment: @Dan, answers go down there. You've short-circuited the SO process by posting it as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

try to use something as a flag to change the style of your view